# Converting limits of integration

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I have the following problem:

Sketch the region of integration for the double integral

$$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{ \pi} y dy dx$$

Rewrite the *rectangular* double integral as a *polar* double integral, and evaluate the polar integral.

Now if I didn't have to convert the integral limits I would know what to do but I'm confused as how I do that.

I know polar coordinates have the form

$$ f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) rdr d\theta$$

and I know how to convert the function, which would give me

$$\iint_R r\sin\theta rdrd\theta$$

but I do not know how to convert the limits of integration and sketch them.
Any help?

Comment: The limits are currently in terms of $x,y$ and you just need to resolve them in terms of $r,\theta$. Think about how to parametrize a rectangular region in terms of polar coordinates.

Comment: Can I do this using these two equations : $r = √ ( x^2 + y^2 )$
$θ = tan^-{1} ( y / x )$

Comment: Why would anyone want to use polar coordinates to compute that integral, other than to make students miserable and confused ... ?

Comment: @CatalinZara I asked myself the same question, seems awfully unnecessary to me.

Comment: @CatalinZara  Students sometimes learn good lessons when they're miserable and confused.  It's not the instructor's job to make them feel good.  The confusion already shown by the OP (in writing $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ instead of $r\sin \theta$ shows that this is a really good problem for him.

Comment: Also, you've been gifted with a problem for which you can easily check your answer.

Comment: @B.Goddard I totally overlooked that $y$ would simply be $r\sin\theta$ and just went straight for the formula $r^2 = x^2 +y^2$. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @B.Goddard I agree that the instructor's job is to help students learn, not to make students feel good. But that doesn't mean forcing them through a path that pretty much guarantees unnecessary hard work and confusion. I teach my students to look for a change of coordinates if the integral looks easier in the new coordinates, not unnecessarily more complicated.

Comment: @CatalinZara  I think we tend, way too often, to judge a problem by whether it's "practical" or if they'll "ever use it."  Some problems exist (and in my opinion these are the most important ones) just to effect a change in the students brain.  Learning to solve a certain kind of problem is not really all that useful in the end.  You can call the work "unnecessary", but it might very well be necessary in effecting the change we want.

Comment: @CatalinZara Totally agree that it is a silly exercise to train the polar coordinate change on. To make a trivial integration into complicated one feels like back to years in military when following the order shades logic and common sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{ \pi} y dy dx$

The region is bound by $x = 0, x = 2, y = 0, y = pi$

Convert to polar
$x = r \cos \theta\\
y = r \sin \theta$

$x=0\\
r\cos \theta = 0\\
\theta = \frac {\pi}{2}$

$x=2\\
r\cos \theta = 2\\
r = 2 \sec \theta$

$y=0\\
r\sin \theta = 0\\
\theta = 0$

$y=\pi\\
r\sin \theta = \pi\\
r = \pi \csc \theta$

What is the angle $\theta$ at the point $(2,\pi)$?

$\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac {\pi}2$

put it together

$\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}2} \int_{0}^{2\sec \theta} (r \sin\theta) r\;dr\;d\theta + \int_{\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi\csc \theta} (r \sin\theta) r\;dr\;d\theta$

You may find it helpful to take one of the integrals and substitute
$\phi = \frac {\pi}{2} - \theta$

$\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}\frac2{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi\sec \phi} (r \cos\phi) r\;dr\;d\phi$

Comment: Okay, could you explain how you got two integrals out of that.

Comment: The region is a rectangle.  Plot it on paper.  You see that there is a corner, and the equation that describes $r$ changes on either side of that corner.

Comment: Finally had some time to work on it, and yes it took nearly 2 pages of work but the answer came out to $\pi ^2/3$ for the left integral and $2\pi ^2/3$, and that totals to $\pi ^2$

Comment: 2 pages?  $\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}2} \int_{0}^{2\sec \theta} (r \sin\theta) r\;dr\;d\theta  = \int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}2} \frac {8 \sin\theta}{3 \cos^3\theta}d\theta = \frac {4}{3} (\cos \theta)^{-2}|_0^{\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}2} = \frac {4}{3} (\tan^2 \theta + 1 )|_0^{\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}2} = \frac {\pi^2}{3}$ and $\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}\frac2{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi\sec \phi} (r \cos\phi) r\;dr\;d\phi = \int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}\frac2{\pi}}\frac 13 \pi^3 sec^2 \phi d\phi= \frac 13 \pi^3 \tan\phi|_{0}^{\tan^{-1}\frac2{\pi}} =  \frac 23 \pi^3$

Comment: Well yes, but in my case I had to lay it all out and show every single step of every integrating trick I used, which is why it ended up being extensive.

Answer (score 0):

You want $0\leq x\leqslant 2$ and $0\leqslant y\leqslant \pi$, which is a rectangle in the first quadrant with one apex at the origin, and two sides on the axii.

So then we want to integrate $\theta$ over that right angle: $0\leqslant \theta\leqslant \pi/2$.

But where shall we integrate $r$?

Polarising the limits gives: $0\leqslant r\cos\theta\leqslant 2$ and $0\leqslant r\sin\theta\leqslant \pi$

So $0\leqslant r\leq \min\{ \frac 2{\cos\theta}, \frac \pi{\sin\theta}\}$

Combining and separating into a disjoint union:

> $${\left\{(r,\theta): 0\leqslant \theta < \arctan\frac \pi 2, 0\leqslant r\leqslant \frac 2{\cos\theta}\right\}}\\\cup{\left\{(r,\theta):\arctan\frac \pi2\leqslant \theta\leqslant \frac \pi 2, 0\leqslant r\leqslant \frac \pi{\sin\theta}\right\}} $$

PS: The answer should obviously be: $\pi^2$ , which is most easily obtained from the original expression, contrary to the normal intent of employing a change of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Even thought this increases the number of integrals, the form of the integrand suggests integrating w.r.t. $\theta$ first. This gives us three integrals, as visualized by this handy plot from Desmos:

[image]

The boundaries for the circles are obvious, leaving us to solve for the boundaries of the lines

$$\begin{cases}y=0 \\ x=0 \\ y=2 \\ x=\pi \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}\theta=0 \\ \theta=\frac{\pi}{2} \\ r\sin\theta=2 \implies \theta = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{r}\right)\\ r\cos\theta=\pi \implies \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{r}\right)\end{cases}$$

which means we can rewrite the integral as

$$I = \int_0^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}r^2\sin\theta\:d\theta\:dr + \int_2^\pi\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{r}\right)}r^2\sin\theta\:d\theta\:dr + \int_\pi^{\sqrt{\pi^2+4}}\int_{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{r}\right)}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{r}\right)}r^2\sin\theta\:d\theta\:dr$$

$$\equiv I_R + I_B + I_G$$

to designate integral red, blue, and green, respectively. The red integral is the most straight forward, so I will show how the calculation for integrals blue and green are done.

$$I_G = \int_\pi^{\sqrt{\pi^2+4}} r^2\left[-\cos\theta\right]_{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{r}\right)}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{r}\right)}\:dr =  \int_\pi^{\sqrt{\pi^2+4}} r^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{(\pi+2)}{r}\right)\:dr$$

$$= \int_\pi^{\sqrt{\pi^2+4}} \frac{\pi}{2}r^2-(\pi+2)r\:dr $$

Similarly, $I_B$ also only gives you a polynomial in $r$ rather than powers of trig. While this integral was more easily integrated in cartesian, keeping this trick in mind for more exotic boundaries or integrands would be useful.